# Usar o <pre> Dentro de uma TAG PHP de um value html

Tags: php, html, value

Boa noite galera.

Mais uma gambiarra que estou em dúvida no meu sistema. Já fiz tudo no começo da página com PHP de fazer uma busca no meu Banco de Dados. Porém tem um campo que estou trazendo através do mysqli_fetch_array que preciso trazer na formatação original que foi digitado em um textarea de um formulário.

Ai na hora de trazer eu criei essa linha no meu HTML (Porém deu errado):

```
<input type="text" id="texto-os" style="height: 150px;" name="texto_os" class="form-control" placeholder="Descreva o Serviço" value="<?php echo '<pre>'.$dados_os['ordem_servico'].'</pre>'?>
```

O resultado disso fica assim: (Tudo em uma linha só (mesmo tendo sido gravado com quebras de linha, e mostrando a tag  como se não tivesse rodando elas.

> `<pre>Texto que vem do Banco de Dados</pre>`

Até mudei para `<input type="text>`"pois quando estava em `<textarea>` não mostrava meu conteúdo do Banco de Dados.

Enfim, em outros códigos uso a tag  depois do echo para trazer a formatação original, mas isso normalmente eu fazia de uma vez no arquivo só com PHP.

Dessa vez pela praticidade, estou trazendo campo a campo as respostas para preencher meu formulário já que ainda não manjo fazer isso via Javascript.

Estou fazendo errado ou realmente não tem como usar o pre dentro da tag value do html?

Abraços

Comment: Precisa mesmo colocar o `<pre></pre>` dentro do `<textarea>` ? Eu testei isso aqui e não funcionou, acho que não dá.

Comment: Então, é que esse campo vai ser um Resumo de Ordem de Serviço. Então a pessoa vai digitar bastante coisa em algumas linhas com quebra. Certeza.
Aí pra ficar melhor de visualizar, vou precisar tratar esse texto de alguma forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `<input type="text">` só aceita uma linha, e não tem como adicionar HTML dentro de value:

```html
<input type="text" value="<pre>olá

Mundo</pre>">
```

E `<br>` também não vai funcionar:

```html
<input type="text" value="olá<br>Mundo">
```

Não é assim que HTML funciona.

O que você deve fazer é trocar `input=text` por `textarea`, assim:

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="30">olá

Mundo</textarea>
```

Comment: Pois é, no caso voltei a usar o textarea e coloquei meu comando php entre abertura e fechamento da tag, ai usando o nl2br e o strip_tags ficou perfeitinho.

Comment: @Rafael não tem sentido usar `nl2br` e depois usar `strip_tags`, isso é extremamente [redundante](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/redundante). Seria melhor só usar strip_tags direto, acaso você tenha conteudo HTML no resultado do mysql, acaso não tiver nem strip_tags faz sentido, preciso ser sincero mas acho que vocês estão confundindo o que esta ocorrendo.

Comment: Verdade, eu tinha tentado sem ele, mas tinha deixado um erro de digitação que me deu erro. Eu não sabia que só em retornar o texto viria já com a formatação inicial. Valeu pela dica, ajudou muito meu caro.

Answer (score -1):

Pra trazer o resultado do banco com quebra de linha utilize a função [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php).

No seu caso fica assim:

```
<input type="text" id="texto-os" style="height: 150px;" name="texto_os" class="form-control" placeholder="Descreva o Serviço" value="<?php echo strip_tags(nl2br($dados_os['ordem_servico']))?>
```

Comment: Ah de fato, eu não lembrava do nl2br, porém ele traz meu código mostrando `<br />` onde deveria quebrar a linha. Será que vou ter que tratar isso com javascript? Ele fica assim. 
`Computador com virus.<br />Não abre Navegador.`

Comment: Editei a resposta, agora coloquei a função `strip_tags` também, vê se funciona.

Comment: Ah legal, com isso funciona sim. Porém não dentro do value. O que fiz então, foi tirar do `<input type="text">` e voltar a usar o `<textarea>`. Ficando agora assim: `<textarea  id="texto-os" style="height: 150px;" name="texto_os" class="form-control" placeholder="Descreva o Serviço"><?php echo strip_tags(nl2br($dados_os['ordem_servico']))?></textarea>`. Deu certinho agora. Obrigado mesmo Leandro, ajudou bastante